# AutoHotKey - change mouse position and click a specific key every time window comes up

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I'm a newbie to AHK, learning the basics. I'm using Notepad as an example - I want to hit the Cancel key **every** time I close Notepad and it asks if I want to Save/Don't Save/Cancel.

I've come up with the script below and it works once but then I have to reload the script to do it again. I want it to hit Cancel every time the question box comes up. I thought Loop would work but am doing something wrong. Any ideas why, anyone?

```
Loop
IfWinExist Notepad,
{
    WinWait Notepad
    WinActivate
    Click 312, 109
    return
}
```

Comment: Use the `{ }` or code button on the toolbar while editing to indent your code 4 spaces so it shows up properly. I've edited your post to show you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Loop
{
    WinWait, Notepad ahk_class #32770
    WinClose
}
```

will do what you want. I've used WinWait to identify the close dialog and WinClose to close it, which is the same as clicking Cancel. I obtained the ahk_class using AutoIt3 Window Spy of course, which is installed along with AHK.

Comment: Many thanks. Your solutions are always simple and precise. I was using Notepad to get my head round clicking on a certain button. What I am actually trying to achieve is this.  I use accounting software which generates statements which should automatically email (using Outlook) to clients. However Outlook complains about each and every email, it pops up a box (with the word "Outlook" in the titlebar) saying that an external program is trying to access email address information, and it gives three choices "Allow/Deny/Help" with Deny being the default key.

Comment: continued  :  What I want to do is use AHK to wait for this window to pop up, then move the mouse to the "Allow" key and click the button.  I need the script to repeat itself the next time the box pops up.  We send out a thousand statements a month and this box pops up for each of them, I want AHK to click the "Allow" button for me in each of them.  I can get AHK to click the Allow key the first time the box pops up but it won't do the successive ones, but I always seem to struggle with the Looping.  Thanks for your assistance

Comment: If the dialog with Allow/Deny/Help has Deny focussed by default, `SendInput {Enter}` would [press the Enter key](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) and thus select Deny. If you need to focus and click other buttons such as Allow you can use something like `SendInput {Tab}{Enter}`.

Comment: Thanks Karan, I'm away from home right now - will try it when I get back. I think I always tend to over-complicate these scripts whereas the solution always seems pure and simple when I see it.  Thanks again for your help.